# How to compress already built jar file?

Tags: java, asp.net, xml, apache, ant

i have built build.xml using ant to create jar file. thing is it jar file size is some 1.7MB. i have to reduce the size. can any one help in to sort out this problem.

Comment: A jar file is basically a zip file, the only way I can see to reduce its size is to reduce the size of the internal components

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Ant Jar Task, then the jar file should be compressed already unless you have explicitly said not to.

> Attribute: compress
>   Description: Not only store data but also compress
>   them, defaults to true. Unless you set the keepcompression attribute
>   to false, this will apply to the entire archive, not only the files
>   you've added while updating.

However, you could try changing the compression level...

> Attribute: level
>   Description:  Non-default level at which file
>   compression should be performed. Valid values range from 0 (no
>   compression/fastest) to 9 (maximum compression/slowest). Since Ant 1.7

See the Ant [documentation on the jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Pack200 which converts the jar into  `Network Transfer Format` based on `JSR 200` . It sometimes further compresses jar significantly.

The javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Pack200.html) contains sample code too.